# Setting M365/Entra AuthenticationMethod Policies with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I would like to programmatically set some of an M365 Tenant's Authentication Method Policies with Powershell.

namely, those found here:
[https://entra.microsoft.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/AuthenticationMethodsMenuBlade/~/AdminAuthMethods](https://entra.microsoft.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/AuthenticationMethodsMenuBlade/%7E/AdminAuthMethods)

For example, I would like to Enable Microsoft Authenticator for All Users.
As well as optional settings like, "Show application name" or "Show geographic location"

This is found by navigating through:
entra.microsoft.com > Identity > Protection > Authentication Methods | Policies >

I can see where via documentation, you can drill through the tenant in Entra:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/how-to-authentication-methods-manage

The closest thing I could find is:

```
Install-module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Signins
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All
Select-MgProfile -Name beta

New-MgUserAuthenticationPhoneMethod -UserId balas@contoso.com
```

Per:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userdevicesettings

But this is at the user-level, and isn't exactly what I'm looking to accomplish.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is partway there:

```
Get-MgPolicyAuthenticationMethodPolicyAuthenticationMethodConfiguration -AuthenticationMethodConfigurationId MicrosoftAuthenticator

Get-MgPolicyAuthenticationMethodPolicyAuthenticationMethodConfiguration -AuthenticationMethodConfigurationId TemporaryAccessPass
```

Comment: According to this documentation, the json specification

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/how-to-mfa-additional-context

I tried this with AdditionalProperties and without.. e.g. featureSettings = <hashtable> and got a null object reference.

Answer (score 0):

I am very close....
using these commands, I can enable the Authentication Method, it enables them, but I cannot fully configure it:

```
$params = @{
    "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.microsoftAuthenticatorAuthenticationMethodConfiguration"
    State = "enabled"
    AdditionalProperties = @{
        featureSettings= @{
            displayAppInformationRequiredState = @{state = 'enabled'}
            displayLocationInformationRequiredState = @{state = 'enabled'}
        }
    }
}
Update-MgPolicyAuthenticationMethodPolicyAuthenticationMethodConfiguration -AuthenticationMethodConfigurationId MicrosoftAuthenticator -BodyParameter $params

$tapparams = @{
    "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.temporaryAccessPassAuthenticationMethodConfiguration"
    State = "enabled"
    IsUsableOnce = $true
}
Update-MgPolicyAuthenticationMethodPolicyAuthenticationMethodConfiguration -AuthenticationMethodConfigurationId TemporaryAccessPass -BodyParameter $tapparams
```

That is... my output looks like this:

```
C:\> $m = Get-MgPolicyAuthenticationMethodPolicyAuthenticationMethodConfiguration -AuthenticationMethodConfigurationId MicrosoftAuthenticator
C:\> $m.AdditionalProperties.featureSettings
                                                                                                                                             Key                                     Value                                                                                                ---                                     -----                                                                                                displayAppInformationRequiredState      {[state, default], [includeTarget, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Obj… 
displayLocationInformationRequiredState {[state, default], [includeTarget, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Obj…

C:\> $m.AdditionalProperties.featureSettings.displayAppInformationRequiredState     
                                                                                                                                             
Key           Value
---           -----
state         default
includeTarget {[targetType, group], [id, all_users]}
excludeTarget {[targetType, group], [id, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$authenticationMethodConfigurationId = "MicrosoftAuthenticator"

$featureSettings = @{
    displayAppInformationRequiredState = @{
        state = "enabled"
        includeTarget = @{
            targetType = "group"
            id = "all_users"
        }
        excludeTarget = @{
            targetType = "group"
            id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        }
    }
    displayLocationInformationRequiredState = @{
        state = "enabled"
        includeTarget = @{
            targetType = "group"
            id = "all_users"
        }
        excludeTarget = @{
            targetType = "group"
            id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        }
    }
}

$params = @{
    "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.microsoftAuthenticatorAuthenticationMethodConfiguration"
    id = $authenticationMethodConfigurationId
    state = "enabled"
    featureSettings = $featureSettings
}

Update-MgPolicyAuthenticationMethodPolicyAuthenticationMethodConfiguration `
    -AuthenticationMethodConfigurationId $authenticationMethodConfigurationId `
    -AdditionalProperties $params
```

Combined these articles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.signins/update-mgpolicyauthenticationmethodpolicyauthenticationmethodconfiguration?view=graph-powershell-1.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/how-to-mfa-additional-context